# Numbers of Tannaim and Amoraim

Tags: history, names, historical-figures, tannaim, amoroim

How many names of Tannaim do we know?

How many names of Ammoraim do we know?

(I am asking about the names and not simply asking "how many were there" because I don't know if there were people that were considered a Tanna or Ammora that we don't know of [whatever that would mean])

Comment: Down-vote with no explanation?

Comment: Re your comment: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/144

Comment: @msh210 So for the record- I would love to receive critical feedback and adjust/edit my question to improve the quality of this site.

Comment: I'll tell you now of some that I know, and those I miss you'll surely pardon.. as with the song I am quoting, you want a number or a list? (It always bugged me in the song that he answers with a list).

Comment: @CashCow A number would be great. (Quoting the source would be equally important).

Comment: Someone below did. Anyone got a source for the answer to the English Country Garden questions? Including actual numbers.

Comment: is this on topic?

Answer (score 6):

From [here](http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/14240-tannaim-and-amoraim) it would appear that there are 277 Tannaim and 1,292 Amoraim mentioned in the Talmudic-Midrashic literature. (Note: A number of Amoraim, e.g. Rav [Abba Arika] is also considered a Tanna according to some *gemarot*.)